# Need Help Writing A Batch Script To Move Certain Files From One Folder To Another

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need help writing a batch script I can run that will take a list of file names ["FileA.jpg", "FileB.jpg", "FileC.jpg"](These file names can be either in a text format or a csv) and finds those files in Folder A and then copies them into Folder B.

If there is an easy way to do this with another kind of script I am definitely open to that. I just need to figure out an automated way to get the job done.

This is the first time I have asked a question and received downvotes... an explanation for that might help as well.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: Downvoters would have to tell you for sure, but I would guess they expected more research and the code you had already tried.  This may be helpful: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it requires a text file which consists of a list of all the files in a simple list format with no quotes called `input.txt`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "FolderA=C:\..[path]"
set "FolderB=C:\...[path]"
REM Above do not end the path with "\"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
copy "!FolderA!\%%~a" "!FolderB!\"
Echo Copied "%%~a" to "!FolderB!"
)
```

And that should work fine.

Mona

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Worked like a charm in conjunction with my R script.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. create a txt called list.txt with the list of file names you want to move and save it in your origin folder.
   2.use the below code to make a bat file and save it in the origin folder.
   3.now run the bat file you saved with admin rights.
2. the files will be copied in C:\copied

   @echo off
   REM (c) 2015
   CLS
   TITLE file finder 
   REM finds files in list.txt file and copies them to C:\copied
   REM CHECK FOR ADMIN RIGHTS
   COPY /b/y NUL %WINDIR%\06CF2EB6-94E6-4a60-91D8-AB945AE8CF38 >NUL 2>&1
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO:NONADMIN
   DEL %WINDIR%\06CF2EB6-94E6-4a60-91D8-AB945AE8CF38 >NUL 2>&1
   :ADMIN
   REM GOT ADMIN RIGHTS
   COLOR 1F
   ECHO Hi, %USERNAME%!
   ECHO Please wait...
   FOR /R "%~dp0" %%I IN (.) DO  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0list.txt") do echo d |xcopy "%%I\%%a" "C:\copies" /e /i
   COLOR 2F
   ECHO.
   ECHO (c) Copying done
   PAUSE
   GOTO:EOF
   :NONADMIN
   REM NO ADMIN RIGHTS
   COLOR 4F
   ECHO.
   ECHO PLEASE RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR
   ECHO.
   pause
   GOTO:EOF